# android for loop magnitude array

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop, netbeans-8.1

I'm doing a project that ask for the highest magnitude earthquake to be displayed in the app. The problem I'm having is that the for loop is crashing the app. If i take the for loop out i get the lowest magnitude earthquake displayed.

I have checked the logcat but its not given me any clues to why.So what I'm asking for i would like some help to point me in the direction to solve this.

Thanks for your help

here is the code

```
private void DisplayInfo(String result){

    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("earthquakes"));

        for (int a = 0; a<arr.length(); a++){

            JSONObject element = arr.getJSONObject(a);
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), element.getString("magnitude"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int[] magnitude = new int[]{0};
            Arrays.sort(magnitude);
            int max = magnitude[magnitude.length - 1];

            for(int i =0; i < magnitude.length; i++){
                if(magnitude[i] > max){
                    max = magnitude[i];

                  //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), element.getString("hello World") + max, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           String value;
            value = "Country Name: " + element.getString("src")
                    + ("\n") + "Date & Time: " + element.getString("datetime")
                    + ("\n") +  "Magnitude: " +  element.getString("magnitude");

            TextView text = new TextView (this);
            text.setText(value);

            setContentView(text);
            Log.d ("String Value >>>>>", value);
        }
         }
            }

    }
```

Logcat from button Clicked

```js
01-09 00:09:45.868: D/Button Click ok(1383): http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo
01-09 00:09:47.928: D/dalvikvm(1383): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 203K, 13% free 2799K/3200K, paused 35ms, total 38ms
01-09 00:10:05.738: E/SoundPool(278): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.738: W/AudioService(278): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.738: E/SoundPool(278): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.738: W/AudioService(278): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.738: E/SoundPool(278): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.748: W/AudioService(278): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.758: E/SoundPool(278): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.758: W/AudioService(278): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.758: E/SoundPool(278): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.768: D/Button Click ok(1383): http://api.geonames.org/earthquakesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username=demo
01-09 00:10:05.778: W/AudioService(278): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.778: E/SoundPool(278): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.778: W/AudioService(278): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.778: E/SoundPool(278): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.808: W/AudioService(278): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.808: E/SoundPool(278): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.808: W/AudioService(278): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.808: E/SoundPool(278): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.838: W/AudioService(278): Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
01-09 00:10:05.848: W/AudioService(278): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
```

Comment: Can you Copy the LogCat Data  with the post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should paste your crash info.
If you catch the exception,you should check the exception info.Or add the try catch block just for JSON,don't including all the code.
Finally you can add a breakpoint,use step by step debug the code.I think you should notice the type cast and element.getString(is null?).

Comment: you are right my for loop is returning null. If i hard code the array and remove the for loop it will find the largest double. So why want the for loop work I'm stuck.